# Display coupon code on Product page [magento v1.9.x]

Tags: php, magento

I want display coupon code on product page. In shopping cart price rules ,i have applied coupon to a particular category. I want to display the coupon on every product page whose category id is specified in shopping cart price rules.

```
$current_sku=$_product->getSku(); // Sku you are looking for

$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($rule->getId()); 

$conditions = $rule->getConditions()->asArray();

foreach( $conditions['conditions'] as $_conditions ):
    foreach( $_conditions['conditions'] as $_condition ):
        $string = explode(',', $_condition['value']);
        for ($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++) {
            $sku = trim($string[$i]);
            if ($sku==$current_sku) {
                    echo $rule->getCouponCode(); // Return coupon code that matches the sku condition
            }
        }
    endforeach;
endforeach;
}
}
```

above code displays coupon code applied to sku on product page.

ref- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/get-shopping-cart-rule-coupon-code